# Prevent second event from firing: click vs. URL hash change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tabs on one of my pages. Each tab loads dynamic content:

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#tab-1">TAB 1</li>
    <li><a href="#tab-2">TAB 2</li>
    <li><a href="#tab-3">TAB 3</li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery** - `onclick`

```
$('li a').on('click', function(e) {
    $('li a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    // Make Ajax call to get data to display...
});
```

Additionally, I'm handling browser's back button. Every time the button is clicked and the tab hash in URL changes, respective tab gets activated and its data retrieved:

**jQuery** - `onhashchange`

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function() {
    var hash = $.trim(window.location.hash);
    var $link = $('li a[href="' + hash + '"]');

    if ($link.length) {
        $link.trigger('click'); // Pass the flow to onclick handler
    }
});
```

The back button works fine. The problem is that when a tab is clicked, **both** events (`onclick` and `onhashchange`) are fired, which leads to making the Ajax call **twice**.

How do I prevent `onhashchange` only if a tab is clicked?

Comment: I don't think this is the correct approach. Keep track of the users hash in JS when he clicks on a link append the hash to the url before the location redirect then you can read and parse from the new url on the next page.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I prevent onhashchange only if a tab is clicked?

Don't.

Instead let the hashchange handler always send the ajax request.

```
// Click on anchor automatically triggers hashchange
$('li a').on('click', function(e) {
    $(this).addClass('active');
});

// hashchange is triggered by both clicks and back button 
$(window).on('hashchange', function() {
   // Make ajax call to fetch content for location.hash
} );
```

Comment: Sorry, I got confused for a minute and wrote something stupid. The idea seems brilliantly simple, thank you :)